# Use link_to to search inside a for loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have an array that has ten names in it and I am looping through them in my html.erb for list items and I want them to be links as well. So when you click on the link you can search for that individual name that was clicked. the issue I have is that it takes me to the path I want but shows my entire database instead of the singular name.

Here is my code for the list.html.erb

```
<%=render 'layouts/search_bar' %>

<h2>Top DJs Worldwide</h2>
  <ol>
    <%  @djsList.each do |n|%>
            <li><%= link_to n,  search_list_path(:params[n] ) %></li>
     <% end %>  
  </ol>

<p><%=link_to "List from DJ MAG",  "http://djmag.com/top100", :target => "_blank "%></p>

<section>
    <%= render "layouts/comments"%>
</section>
```

This is the controller for this page

```
class DjsController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @djsList = ["Hardwell", "Armin Van Buuren", "Avicii", "Tiesto", "David Guetta", "Dimitri Vegas & Like Mike", "Nicky Romero", "Steve Aoki", "Afrojack",  "Dash Berlin"]
  end
end
```

And here is the model for the database

```
class DjList < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.search search_term
    return scoped unless search_term.present?
    where(['dj_name LIKE ?' , "%#{search_term}%"])
  end

end
```

here is the search_controller.rb

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @search = DjList.search(params[:dj_name]).all

    @listShows = [ "Dash Berlin at SoundGarden Hall, Friday, January 31, 2014" ]

  end
end
```

Comment: From your controller, it looks as if you're rendering the `list` action, right? Where is your call to `DjList.search`? Can you post that code, too?

Comment: According to this code, its not called at all.

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for how to set it up to call `DjList.search`?

Comment: What is a `DjList` supposed to be? What are you trying to see in your view when you render a `DjList`? Is a `DjList` a list of DJs (similar to the array of names)? Is it a list of tracks by each DJ? The solution depends on the answer to that question.

Comment: DjList is the database that has a list of similar names to the array, I am trying to check if the name is on the DjList database.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a typo? (`:params` should be `params`).

```
<li><%= link_to n,  search_list_path(:params[n] ) %></li>
```

So:

```
<li><%= link_to n,  search_list_path( params[n] ) %></li>
```

Also - how are you telling the path what the name of this parameter is? you're just passing a raw *value* - params have to be a key-value pair, and you've given it no key. Try:

```
<li><%= link_to n,  search_list_path( :dj_name => params[n] ) %></li>
```

Finally... I'm pretty sure you're inside a loop of *different* dj-names... and you want each link to go to a *different* dj-name (not the one currently stored in params, but the one listed in this iteration of the loop. So use that instead:

```
<li><%= link_to n,  search_list_path( :dj_name => n ) %></li>
```